# What is M and L in GeometryDrawing?

Tags: wpf

What is the meaning of M and L in this code?

```
<GeometryDrawing x:Name=”Front” Brush=”Red”
Geometry=”M0,260 L0,600 L110,670 L110,500 L190,550 L190,710 L300,775
L300,430 L150,175”/>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

M is for move to, L is for line to, etc.
You should check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/shapes-and-basic-drawing-in-wpf-overview section **XAML Abbreviated Syntax**.

Or better https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-markup-syntax.

Comment: Your links are broken thanks to Microsoft, but this outlines why link only answers are not appreciated on Stack Overflow.